# from A4 paper to A5 and keeping the number of characters per line

Tags: margins, paper-size

I have written my thesis for A4 paper using the memoir class. I would like to print one version on A5 paper. Is there a way to reduce margins automatically in order to keep the same layout for the text?

I mean, I have for instance 70 characters per line, I would like to keep this number of characters per line by decreasing the size of the margin.

Thanks for your help.

edit: here is a picture of what I want to do (copy/paste in gimp):

original A4 paper

[image: a4]

A5 paper (of course I want larger vecrtical margin, but the horizontal margins are perfect).

[image: a5]

Comment: What about reducing font size?

Comment: Why don't you use `pdfpages` and `\includepdf`?

Comment: Unless you used unusual large margins the textwidth in the A4 paper is larger than a A5 paper, so it can't work without changing the font size.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear enough. I would like to keep the same font size and picture size (or something close at least). I used the standard margins of memoir class that are quite large for A4. So I would like to decrease as much margins as possible. It does not matter if I have more pages at the end. I just want to keep something easy to read.
note that I will print an official version in A4, the A5 version is for me.

Comment: Perhaps with very minimalistic margins and A5 landscape format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `geometry`

## a5paper

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage[a5paper,textwidth=5in,textheight=7in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
  \kant[1-40]
\end{document}
```

[image]

## a4paper

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage[a4paper,textwidth=5in,textheight=7in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
  \kant[1-40]
\end{document}
```

[image]

I have just fixed the `textwidth` to be same for both versions. Adjust the `textwidth` and `textheight` as suitable to you and keep them same for both papers.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is exactly what I want to do. It works, I just have to make few arrangement with my chapter style.